# UIActivityViewController to share any content in ios9 , is not working as expected in case of saving notes

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

`UIActivityViewController` to share content is not working as expected  in case of saving notes in `ios9`. Here is my piece of code :

```
title,description,url are contains different contents to share.//

NSArray *dataToShare= @[title,description,url];
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Thanks for any input very much in advance.

Comment: You left out the important information. What behavior are you seeing and what behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Before, ios9 same code share every object in NSArray *dataToShare= @[title,description,url];
    but now only first object is showing while saving content in NOTES(one of the option showed by share screen).

Comment: Sorry, for bad explanation. I have solved my problem by contantinate the string..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved this problem by Concatenate the different string to one for saving all content in NOTES.

```
NSString *url=@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APPNAME/idXXXXXXXXX";
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download ECG app %@ and get free reward points!",url];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: this alert is coming..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760970/uiactivityviewcontroller-share-text-in-whats-app-and-all-sharing-option

Comment: please read question carefully i have mentioned "while saving notes".

Comment: yes , but we can share text and image both together in whats app ?