# UIActivityViewController Share text in whats app and all sharing option

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, info.plist

In my application I used `UIActivityViewController` to share text in Whatsapp, Facebook and Twitter etc.

I am working in iOS 9 and Xcode Version 7.2.
When I click on Whatsapp icon and click on particular contact person for share then pop up the following alert view:

[image]

When I click on **OK**, I get the following warning in debug pane:

> plugin net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension invalidated

and i also set `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to **whatsapp** in .plist file but it didn't work.

I want to share text in all sharing option without any customized control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a good look at their FAQ page: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: @AshutoshDave this is only for whats app rght ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503099/1850983
check may help you.

Comment: @rameshbhuja Yes. It is only for whatsapp.

Comment: you can check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem.. It is caused most probably by using NSString instead of NSURL, here is a working code:

```
-(void) share {
NSString* shareText = @"Sharing an eddress with you";
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eddress.co/EDDRSS"];
NSArray *shareArray = @[shareText, website];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareArray applicationActivities:nil];

[activityVC setValue:@"Someone shared an eddress with you" forKey:@"subject"];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```